# Team Explorer Everywhere fails to auto merge conflicts and fails to display resolve conflicts screen in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

Our software group is using Team Explorer Everywhere Eclipse plugin on Eclipse Helios Our OS is Debian Lenny. Some of the team members are experiencing some weird behavior when they have conflicting changes and when they get the latest.

For instance, right now when we get the latest:

Bunch of conflicts return

"Unable to perform the get operation because you have a conflicting property +x" error.

Then another bunch returns

"Unable to perform the get operation because you have a conflicting edit" error.

Then below all these warning messages eclipse displays the following error:

"Resolving multiple conflicts requires a single resolution type".

Instead of displaying the resolve conflict screen, eclipse does nothing, everytime we get the latest we receive these error messages, so we stare at the screen clueless about how to fix this error.

conflicting property +x error makes me think that there is some permission conflict between the source control and workspace, Though I am not quite sure what we are doing wrong.

Can somebody shed some light on what might be the issue here?

Comment: This certainly sounds like a bug.  The best place to report this would be the Team Explorer Everywhere forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tee so that we can get diagnostic information from you.

Comment: (In particular, it sounds like somebody has edited a file and set it executable, and is trying to merge in a conflicting edit.  I'm not sure why this would be unable to be resolved, so if that's true, that would be a bug.)

Comment: Thank you I posted the same question to Team Explorer Everywhere Forum, hoping to get some feedback.

Answer (score 8):

This does seem like a bug. I get this all the time, and use two work-arounds:

1) Go to each conflicting file and do "Get Latest". When you do this file by file instead of project wide, any conflicting files will bring up the Resolve window.

2) At the project level, instead of "Get Latest" do "Get Specific Version" and choose "Latest" with the option to Force the download. That option is usually a checkbox with text like "Force get of file versions..." or something like that.